# phantomjs: include jquery to hide or click element

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs

Im trying to get a screenshot from a webpage by previously hiding the cookie policy. Something like:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 375, height: 667 };
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A366 Safari/600.1.4';

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg, line, source) {
    console.log('console> ' + msg);
};

var fs = require('fs');

page.open('https://www.twitter.com/mmarkmiller/status/714525180668850176', function(status) {
    console.log('Status: ' + status);
    page.includeJs('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js', function() {
        (page.evaluate(function() {
            console.log('Evaluating!');
            // jQuery is loaded, now manipulate the DOM
            var $button = $('div[jsnamespace="EuCookieSheet"]');
            $button.hide();
        }));
    });
    fs.write('test.html', page.content, 'w');
    page.render('teto.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

But I get no "Evaluating!" text in console log displayed and both rendered html and png files have the cookies policy visible. I see that jquery is included at the end of body in saved html but seems that the page.evaluate part is not working

What could i be missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There Jquery is already exist, open the console of your browser and execute `$`. Due to it, your callback `page.includeJs` won't work. You already can use jquery there, inside of evaluate context.

And also: there is no css selector like `div[jsnamespace="EuCookieSheet"]`, you can do what you want on pure js:

```
function click(sel){var event=document.createEvent('MouseEvents');event.initMouseEvent('click',1,1,window,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null);document.querySelector(sel).dispatchEvent(event);}
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 375, height: 667 };
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/12A366 Safari/600.1.4';

page.onConsoleMessage = function (msg, line, source) {
    console.log('console> ' + msg);
};

var fs = require('fs');

page.open('https://www.twitter.com/mmarkmiller/status/714525180668850176', function(status) {
    console.log('Status: ' + status);
        page.evaluate(function(click){
       console.log('Evaluating!');
        document.querySelector('div[jsnamespace="EuCookieSheet"]').style="display: none;"
        },click);
    fs.write('test.html', page.content, 'w');
    page.render('teto.png');
  phantom.exit();
})
```

Comment: [console.log not working after jquery inject](https://qnalist.com/questions/5147963/console-log-not-working-after-jquery-inject)

Comment: i've tested [your modified script](http://pastebin.com/7i8gRBcp) on an empty page (without jquery) - all works fine: it prints: `console> Evaluating!`

Comment: But `phantom.exit();` fires too early. Maybe you need to use `setTimeout(phantom.exit,2000)`.

Comment: nice! how would it be for  click event instead of modifying css?

Comment: You can click on any element, by using [jquery click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function e.g. `$("#id_submit").click();` or you may use pure js function: `function click(sel){var event=document.createEvent('MouseEvents');event.initMouseEvent('click',1,1,window,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,null);document.querySelector(sel).dispatchEvent(event);}` to use it: `click("#id_submit")`